# Floor and Ceiling function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

prove that x is a real number then $\lfloor −x \rfloor = −\lceil x\rceil$ and $\lceil −x \rceil = −\lfloor x \rfloor$. If I were to put a real number say like $1$, wouldn't it be right? But if I put a value like $1.5$ it would be incorrect? I don't think this is the way I should be proving it though so could anyone help me out.

Comment: One approach: Consider two cases for whether $x\geq0$ and work on it explicitly.

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted this.  I was unfortunately not gifted with psychic powers, and I don't see any comment directed to the OP indicating how they can improve the question.

Comment: It’s correct with $x=1.5$: $\lfloor-1.5\rfloor=-2$, $\lceil 1.5\rceil=2$, $\lceil-1.5\rceil=-1$, and $\lfloor1.5\rfloor=1$. You may have been calculating the floor and ceiling of $-1.5$ incorrectly: remember, $-2<-1.5<-1$, so $-2$ is the floor and $-1$ the ceiling, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: As you noted, it’s easy to see that the identities hold when $x$ is an integer. Suppose that $x$ is not an integer; then there is an integer $n$ such that $n<x<n+1$. Multiplying this by $-1$, we see that $-(n+1)<-x<-n$. What are $\lfloor x\rfloor$, $\lceil x\rceil$, $\lfloor-x\rfloor$, and $\lceil-x\rceil$ in terms of $n$? Do the identities hold?

If you think in visual or physical terms, it might be helpful to visualize multiplying the number line by $-1$ as rotating it $180$° about the point $0$, so that the numbers $x$ and $-x$ change places. If $x$ is trapped between two integers, it will still be trapped between their negatives after the rotation, **but the order of the three numbers will have been reversed**.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$ 
\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor =x-m\\ 
\left\lfloor -x \right\rfloor =-x-m\\ 
\left\lceil x \right\rceil =x+(1-m)\\ 
\left\lceil -x \right\rceil =-x+(1-m)
$

where $m = y \mod 1$, which means $m>=0$.