# Is there an equivalence between $\big\lceil \frac{a}{M} \big\rceil$ and $floor$ that works regardless of wether $a$ and/or $M$ are integers or not?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there a way to rewrite a $ceiling$ as a $floor$?

I want to write $\big\lceil \frac{a}{M} \big\rceil$ in terms of $floor$ and possibly $\bmod M$ if necessary.

Given $q := \big\lfloor \frac{a}{M} \big\rfloor$ and $r = a \bmod m$, I thought the following were equivalent

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Big\lceil \frac{a}{M} \Big\rceil &=
\begin{cases}
q &\;\text{if }\ r = 0\\
q+1 &\;\text{if }\ r \neq 0
\end{cases} &&(1)\\
\\
&= \Big\lfloor \frac{a-1+M}{M} \Big\rfloor &&(2)\\
\\
&= \Big\lfloor \frac{a-1}{M} \Big\rfloor + 1 &&(3)
\end{aligned}
$$

But after graphing them on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sthx852eez), I've come to find out the latter two, $(2)$ and $(3)$, seem to be equivalent to $\big\lceil \frac{a}{M} \big\rceil$ iif $a$ and $M$ are integers or something like that. Maybe $a$ and $M$ have to be positive as well for $(2)$ and $(3)$ to be equivalent to $(1)$.

Is there an equivalence between $\big\lfloor \frac{a}{M} \big\rfloor$ and $floor$ ((other than the equivalence shown in $(1)$)) that works regardless of wether $a$ and/or $M$ are integers or not?

---

By the way, using $Iverson\ bracket\ notation$, $(1)$ can be written as

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Big\lceil \frac{a}{M} \Big\rceil &= \Big\lfloor \frac{a}{M} \Big\rfloor + [[a \bmod M \neq 0]]
\end{aligned}
$$

where $[[condition]]$ denotes $Iverson\ bracket\ notation$ defined as

$$
[[condition]]=
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } condition\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
$$

Comment: FYI, the Wikipedia's statements about floor & ceiling function negative values equalities that I used are dealt with in [Floor and Ceiling function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1216615/602049).

Comment: How does desmos define $a \mod m$ when $m$ is not an integer?  $\lceil K \rceil = \begin{cases}\lfloor K \rfloor&K\in \mathbb Z\\ \lfloor K\rfloor + 1&K\not \in \mathbb Z\end{cases}$ so your only issue is whether $\frac aM\in \mathbb Z$ or in other words whether there exists a $k\in \mathbb Z$ so that $a=kM$.  This is the definition of $M\mid a$ regardless as to whether $M$ or $a$ are integers or not.  If $M\in \mathbb Z$ then this is true precisely when $0=a\mod M$. So your issue is *entire* based on what $a\mod M$ *means* when $M\not\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: For example what is $7 \mod \frac {7}{13}$.  We *do* know that $\frac 7{13} \mid 7$ because there is an integer $\color{blue}{13}$ so that $7 = \color{blue}{13}\cdot \frac {7}{13}$.  But does that mean $0 = 7\mod \frac {7}{13}$?  What *does* $7\mod \frac 7{13}$ *mean*?

Comment: @fleablood Variants of the modulo operation ("mod(x, M)") are presented in [Wikipedia Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Variants_of_the_definition). Desmos seems to define "mod" in terms floored division. This can be seen by comparing the graphs in this [Desmos Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hkcxfgdvvc) to the graphs in the ["Quotient and remainder using floored division" image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#/media/File:Divmod_floored.svg).

Comment: @fleablood As you can see, in both cases, a positive divisor (i.e. M > 0) yields a positive "mod(x, M)"; while a negative divisor (i.e. M' = -M < 0) yields a negative "mod(x, M')".

Comment: Updated link to Desmos graph: [5 types of integer divisions and their corresponding quotient, remainder, and Modulo operation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h6ests1ilt). All 5 definitions have the property that $\operatorname{mod}(nM, M) = nM \bmod M = 0$ for any integer $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [Relations among the functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Relations_among_the_functions) section of Wikipedia's article, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $-\lceil x \rceil = \lfloor -x \rfloor$, which means

$$\lceil x \rceil = -\lfloor -x \rfloor \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

To prove this, let $x = n + r$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0 \le r \lt 1$. If $r = 0$, then $\lceil x \rceil = n$ and $-\lfloor -x \rfloor = -(-n) = n$. If $r \gt 0$, then $\lceil x \rceil = n + 1$ while $-\lfloor -x \rfloor = -\lfloor -n - r \rfloor = -(-n - 1) = n + 1$.

Thus, \eqref{eq1A} holds for both cases. For your particular expression, using $x = \frac{a}{M}$ in \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$\left\lceil \frac{a}{M} \right\rceil = -\left\lfloor -\frac{a}{M} \right\rfloor \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$